# AWS CodeDeploy Instance specific configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

*I'm not native, so first I'm sorry for my bad English.*

What is the best practice for instance specific configuration in AWS CodeDeploy?

I want to deploy server for multiple instances, and I also want to register some cron job (like, daily report?) on just **one** of these instances. I'm using AWS CodeDeploy, and looks like there's no simple option to do such thing.

I have some solutions but not very satisfying. One is separating Deployment Group. Means I have to manage some additional Revisions. The other is add tags to EC2 instances and diverge with the tags. It feels too tricky. Is there any other recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no best practice for instance specific configuration in CodeDeploy for instances in the same deployment group. I recommend creating a separate application entirely running on a different instance if you want to run jobs like daily report, so that the job will not interfere with the normal functioning of your application (for example, if the job consumes all the CPU, then your server on that same box will be impacted.)